# Then function not executing

Tags: callback, ethereum, web3js

So I've been trying to execute the mint function after the contract.methods.registerVoter function goes through but I had no luck. Only the contract.methods.registerVoter function gets executed and nothing happens in the then function. What am I doing wrong?

```
export async function registerVoter(walletAddress) {

   const contract = await getContract();

   const votingToken = await getTokenCotract();

   const tokenAddress = await getTokenAddress();

   const web3 = window.web3;

   contract.methods.registerVoter(walletAddress, tokenAddress).send({from: walletAddress}).then(() => {
       votingToken.methods.mint(walletAddress, 1).send({from: walletAddress})
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the send function into getContract is not a promise

Comment: the getContract just returns an instance of a contract

Comment: `function registerVoter(address _voter, address _token) external {
        require(registeredVoter[_voter] == false, "WKNDElection::You have already registered");

        registeredVoter[_voter] = true;

        emit VoterRegistered(_voter);
    }`

Comment: I've tested te functions separately and they both work so there isn't a problem with any function itself, it's just that the program never enters the then part.

Comment: it is because none of the functions return a promise